# Material UI table header zIndex does not apply

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need table header cell to appear above other elements on hover. Currently as I hover, it appears under table body and under other cells.

```
const renderColumnLabel = (value) => {
  const [hoverRef, isHover] = useHover(); //hook which determine should we provide tooltip or not 
  return (
    <div ref={hoverRef}>
      {isHover && (
        <Paper className={classes.cellHead__hover}>
          <Typography>{value}</Typography>
        </Paper>
      )}
      <Typography>{value}</Typography>
    </div>
  );
};`
```

MY CLASSES:

```
cellHead__hover: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  backgroundColor: 'inherit',
  zIndex: 100000,
}
```

Why does Z index not apply to table header in MUI

Comment: It'd be valuable if you create a debuggable example using something like https://codesandbox.com (and sharing the link) so we can try to debug it faster.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-sound-zzdw5l?file=/src/MainTable.js